# Convert controller code to a reusable directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I built this "component" in Angular.js but I don't know what is the best way to encapsulate it into a reusable element directive.

Here is the current code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OdWoUXOpoZ6pIVbMUVXk?p=preview

Here is how I would like to use it

```html
<span ng-bind="selection"></span>

<checkbox-list ng-model="selection">

    <checkbox value="name1">Label 1</checkbox>
    <checkbox value="name1">Label 2</checkbox>
    <checkbox value="name1">Label 3</checkbox>
    <checkbox value="name1">Label 4</checkbox>
    <checkbox value="name1">Label 5</checkbox>

</checkbox-list>
```

The best behaviour would be to be able to reuse the `<checkbox>` even outside of `<checkbox-list>`. Also, I think it would be boilerplate to bind a model to each `<checkbox>`, at least not from html code. But using `<checkbox>` outside of the list would require a model binding.

I used `<checkbox>` instead of `<input type="checkbox">` because I want to have a custom design for the checkboxes, which involves custom template and css.

Could you guys give me some advices on this situation? A plunker code would be much appreciated but not required, I just need your opinion.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? I seems to me that all you need is two simple directives. Have you read the docs on directives? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The bindings are tricky to make if you want the child directive be usable outside of it's parent. I don't know how to bind a model to a `<checkbox>` without specifying an explicit attribute and then importing it to the scope using `{ model: '=' }`.

Comment: Basically, the child directive should have a scope only when it's outside of `<checkbox-list>`, otherwise it should use the parent scope.

Comment: `{ model: '=?'}` will do a conditional binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a plunker with working reusable directives.  Is this what you were looking for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/L0AwTtCyLxg9fbtzN0oC?p=preview

I modified the example you showed slightly to allow you to set the "value" for the checkboxes themselves from the `<checkbox-list>` tag

**UPDATE**
I have modified the code to allow you to have the `<checkbox>` directive alone and give it a model object to bind to

**DOUBLE UPDATE**

Here is a more complete [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/71awgBJCi1wZvXsynPLF?p=preview) with all your requirements based on our convo

Comment: I've updated your code a little bit to work as I need it. Could you confirm that I'm doing everything well? http://plnkr.co/edit/vzgs1HufcFiaWd9vRnPN?p=preview

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm overwriting the model in the link function. This way it can't be used in a ng-repeat where the models contain actual data. Am I right?

Comment: I modified your new changes a touch to wrap it in an ng-repeat to show that it doesn't overwrite the model [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DZsFgimJy9rlOYP4kMkc?p=preview). It does look like everything will be fine though with your changes

Comment: Here is what I meant. If you define models with real data, not empty object, it doesn't work. Maybe it should work because this way there are two data entry points (the attributes, value/checked OR the model). http://plnkr.co/edit/HtDKqjznWduGsPMAxW8i?p=preview

Comment: **UPDATE** This one should have the desired effect.  Sorry for having so many plunks :) [http://plnkr.co/edit/71awgBJCi1wZvXsynPLF?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/71awgBJCi1wZvXsynPLF?p=preview)

Comment: Yep, that is what I needed. Also I will check if model.active is set, otherwise I will check for the existence of checked attribute. Thanks Erik for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46601/discussion-between-andrew-and-erik-donohoo)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with inherited scope [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RafPTV5mhXniPp8kjnli?p=preview):

```
var app=angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller("MainCtrl",function ($scope, $interval) {

  $scope.manufacturers = { nume1: true, nume4: true };

  $scope.$watch('manufacturers', function() {
    $scope.updateValue();
  }, true);

  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    var activeItems = [];

    for (var key in $scope.manufacturers) {
      if ($scope.manufacturers[key] === true)
        activeItems.push(key);
    }

    $scope.value = activeItems.join(',');
  }

});

app.directive("d", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'dir.html',  
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         }

    };
});
```

For other possible implementation of a directive see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iOXJ5PJbIU6KO96wUDOA?p=info).